# Allow .htaccess on apache2+nginx?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

Is there a way to make apache2 consider .htaccess files when the server also uses nginx?

I'm trying to configure my localhost the same way as our hosting works, they have Plesk panel and all the traffic comes through nginx and then is forwarded to apache that handles PHP and the .htaccess does work there.

Currently I have this in the apache's site-enabled config:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName my.domain.name
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my.domain.name
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my.domain.name.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my.domain.name.access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/my.domain.name/">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and nginx sites-enabled:

```
server {
    listen   80;

    root /var/www/my.domain.name/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name my.domain.name;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

     }

     location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

I tried changing `location ~ /\.ht` to `allow all` and also completely removing it and still no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "server also uses nginx" ??

Comment: nginx is set up on port 80, therefore when someone visits the website that goes straight to nginx. And nginx just forwards it to port 8080 where apache is listening. That's just my understanding of it, I also added nginx's config in the main post.

Comment: I don't think nginx running on the server should affect behavior of .htaccess file for apache. Whenever I gets some time, I will try to do the same setup on my end to find out the exact problem.